# Put points round into circular arc used in java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, graphics

I have me math question: I have known a circle center and radius, and have some uncertain number of points called N, my question is how to put the points on the circular arc, I cannot like put the points around the whole circumference, other as this link: http://i.6.cn/cvbnm/2c/93/b8/05543abdd33b198146d473a43e1049e6.png
in this link, you can read point is circle center, other color is some points, you can see these points around the arc.

Edit - in short: I have known a circle center and radius, so I want to generate some point around the circle center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure, but I checked this with simple Swing JComponent and seems ok.

```
Point center = new Point(100, 100); // circle center

int n = 5; // N
int r = 20; // radius
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    double fi = 2*Math.PI*i/n;
    double x = r*Math.sin(fi + Math.PI) + center.getX();
    double y = r*Math.cos(fi + Math.PI) + center.getY();
    //g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, y));
}
```

Comment: I updated equations to get better (visual) result (first point is always on top of circle center).

Comment: i test your code,but your points average locate whole circle path,can you put the points locate a part of the whole circle,as 2/3 of whole circle

Comment: @ Grzegorz Szpetkowski,you say "first point is always on top of circle center", can you tell me how to put the first point  at any place?thank you,sorry for my maths.

Comment: @pengwang: Just change fi to position the points at different angles.  For a 90 degree shift, add or subtract `Math.PI / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to accomplish here. The general idea of most of it is fairly simple though. There are 2*Pi radians in a circle, so once you've decided what part of a circle you want to arrange your points over, you multiply that percentage by 2*pi, and divide that result by the number of points to get the angle (in radians) between the points.

To get from angular distances to positions, you take the cosine and sine of the angle, and multiply each by the radius of the circle to get the x and y coordinate of the point relative to the center of the circle. For this purpose, an angle of 0 radians goes directly to the right from the center, and angles progress counter-clockwise from there.

Comment: thank you your answer,in short: i want to generate some points around the circle.